# Build failed on launchpad

Tags: launchpad, glib

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Launchpad failed to build after “quickly submitubuntu”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156339/launchpad-failed-to-build-after-quickly-submitubuntu)

I am still getting this error:

> /bin/sh: 1: glib-compile-schemas: not found

The full log:
https://launchpadlibrarian.net/109259873/buildlog_ubuntu-precise-i386.facebookupload_12.07.6_FAILEDTOBUILD.txt.gz

I already tried to add libglib2.0-bin  on the dependencies but this fix didn't work.

I tried to run quickly configure dependencies but this command is going to add it under " Depends:" instead of "Build-Depends:"

Each time I run quickly submit the control file is going to be overwritten.

Does anyone found how to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure that you added it in the build-depends field? I think you've added the correct package: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=glib-compile-schemas&mode=exactfilename&suite=precise&arch=any

Comment: I can't add n the build-depends because quickly recreate this file

Answer (score 0):

Please, allow me to redirect you to [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156339/launchpad-failed-to-build-after-quickly-submitubuntu), as this issue is addressed in this question (it's a bug with quickly, NOT your app. Or you don't have libglib2 installed)

Comment: I have installed libglib2, I can create a package and install it on another machine and it works.
I still don't understand how to solve it, I tried to add manualy libglib2 but when I run debuild -S I am getting some errors about signature.

Comment: Will your program build if you type in "package --extras" after you cd into the program folder?